How to do zonal statistics on a monthly composite of sentinel 2 data in GEE?
I'm using google earth engine to create a table showing monthly averages of band values, which are also averaged across some lakes. Here is an example of my code.
First, I pull down the sentinel 2 data and create a monthly composite. I pretty much used the code from this stack exchange post
//some made up geometry
var geometry = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-113.0857421875, 41.602598130446786],
          [-113.0857421875, 40.509091454509885],
          [-111.6794921875, 40.509091454509885],
          [-111.6794921875, 41.602598130446786]]], null, false);

//download sentinel-2 data most recent five years
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
                  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2024-01-01')
                  .filterBounds(geometry)

//Monthly Images
var months = ee.List.sequence(1,12);
var years = ee.List.sequence(2019,2023); 

// monthly composite
var monthlyImages =  ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  years.map(function (y) {
  return months.map(function(m){
  var w = dataset.select([ 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B8A', 'B11', 'B12']).filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'))
           .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
           .mean()
           .set('system:time_start',ee.Date.fromYMD(y,m,1).millis());
  return w.set('year', y)
           .set('month', m)
           .set('date', ee.Date.fromYMD(y,m,1))
           .set('system:time_start',ee.Date.fromYMD(y,m,1).millis()) 

});
}).flatten());

print(monthlyImages)

Next, I want to go through my shape (in this example called geometry) and create an average value for every band per month.
so first I have a function for zonal statistics
//function to extract mean values
function zonalStats(ic, fc, params) {
  // Initialize internal params dictionary.
  var _params = {
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale: null,
    crs: null,
    bands: null,
    bandsRename: null,
    imgProps: null,
    imgPropsRename: null,
    datetimeName: 'datetime',
    datetimeFormat: 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
  };

  // Replace initialized params with provided params.
  if (params) {
    for (var param in params) {
      _params[param] = params[param] || _params[param];
    }
  }

  // Set default parameters based on an image representative.
  var imgRep = ic.first();
  var nonSystemImgProps = ee.Feature(null)
    .copyProperties(imgRep).propertyNames();
  if (!_params.bands) _params.bands = imgRep.bandNames();
  if (!_params.bandsRename) _params.bandsRename = _params.bands;
  if (!_params.imgProps) _params.imgProps = nonSystemImgProps;
  if (!_params.imgPropsRename) _params.imgPropsRename = _params.imgProps;

  // Map the reduceRegions function over the image collection.
  var results = ic.map(function(img) {
    // Select bands (optionally rename), set a datetime & timestamp property.
    img = ee.Image(img.select(_params.bands, _params.bandsRename))
      .set(_params.datetimeName, img.date().format(_params.datetimeFormat))
      .set('timestamp', img.get('system:time_start'));

    // Define final image property dictionary to set in output features.
    var propsFrom = ee.List(_params.imgProps)
      .cat(ee.List([_params.datetimeName, 'timestamp']));
    var propsTo = ee.List(_params.imgPropsRename)
      .cat(ee.List([_params.datetimeName, 'timestamp']));
    var imgProps = img.toDictionary(propsFrom).rename(propsFrom, propsTo);

    // Subset points that intersect the given image.
    var fcSub = fc.filterBounds(img.geometry());

    // Reduce the image by regions.
    return img.reduceRegions({
      collection: fcSub,
      reducer: _params.reducer,
      scale: _params.scale,
      crs: _params.crs
    })
    // Add metadata to each feature.
    .map(function(f) {
      return f.set(imgProps);
    });
  }).flatten().filter(ee.Filter.notNull(_params.bandsRename));

  return results;
}

then I set my params and try to run it
// Define parameters for the zonalStats function.
var params = {
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 20,
  bands: [ 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B8A', 'B11', 'B12'], 
  bandsRename: ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'red_edge1', 'red_edge2', 'red_edge3', 'NIR', 'red_edge4', 'SWIR_1', 'SWIR_2'],
  datetimeName: 'date',
  datetimeFormat: 'YYYY-MM-dd'
};

// Extract zonal statistics per point per image.
var SentinelStats = zonalStats(monthlyImages, geometry, params);

but I get this error
FeatureCollection (Error) Error in map(ID=0): Dictionary.rename: Duplicate key: [date].
